# Configuring Entity Framework In ASP.NET 5 using a DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to completely separate the repository / data access later whilst still using configuration in the main project (through appsettings.json)

My current solution is either to hard code the connection string in the `OnConfiguring` method in the DbContext which is not ideal. Or perhaps create a config file just for the repository layer and read from that.

I would like the main project (web service in this case) to be completely independent of the data access layer (as I will be communicating to it using a service layer anyway), but be able to configure it at start-up using the default appsettings.json

Is there a good approach of doing this? Or must the main project have a reference to the repository layer.

**Project layout:**

```
Project.WebService
    - Startup.cs
    - EmployeeController.cs
    - appsettings.json
Project.Service
    - EmployeeService.cs
    - EmployeeDTO.cs
Project.DAL
    - DbContext.cs
    - EmployeeRepository.cs
Project.Entities
    - Employee.cs
```

The WebService references the Service, the Service references the DAL and the DAL references the Entities / POCOs

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connString = Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectionString"];

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connString));
}
```

The above doesn't work anyway with the DbContext being in another class library. The following exception gets thrown.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No database providers are configured.
>   Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your
>   DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up
>   services.

Which is one reason why I hard-coded the connection string into the `OnConfiguring` method.

Does anyone have any good approaches / solutions for this or am I missing something? The web service doesn't need to know what database it is talking to, or have any reference to it at all. It simply calls a service, a receives a DTO or, sends a DTO.

Comment: Using DI, you can easily separate every layers but you will always have a reference to your DAL from your web project.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, it just feels like you should have to need a reference if you're just using it for dependency injection, when I wont' be interacting with that layer directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hook up all dependencies:**
 If you really insist on your webservice not having a reference to your DAL, you could always try an 'IT ops' layer.

Some infrastructure layer (which you can call for instance "InfratructureService", which has a reference to all your projects (webservice, Service, DAL, Entities). In this infrastructure layer you create the container which every project is going to use.

Then all your projects should have a class which is called "ConfigureMe" or something, with 1 method called "Configure" for instance. That method takes as parameter an instance of the container which was build in InfratructureService. At startup your Webservice is going to give "InfratructureService" a sign to build the container and call every "Configure" method of every "ConfigureMe" class of every project it references.

In those "Configure" methods each project can ofcourse register their own depedencies in the container. And voila, all dependencies are known in the container without making unnecessary references and ready to be resolved via constructor injection.

**The connectionstring problem:**
 Now as for your hardcoded connectionstring, you know about [configuration](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) in asp.net core right? Once you've set up your configuration as described [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects) you can insert via dependency injection the IOptions anywhere you want. That means also in your DAL.

Let me know if anything is unclear or you can't figure it out.

Comment: Cheers. I'll have a look and get back to you. InfrastructureService sounds interesting though